# POST an appointment/reservation - CORS Policy problems

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest

I try to post a dictionary with data for a reservation. But chrome logs this error:`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/reservations' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

This is strange since I can post images, videos, html content because I put a `@CrossOrigin` annotation above my controllers. But with this particular post request it doesn’t seem to work.

rest controller:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200",
        maxAge=2000,allowedHeaders="header1,header2",
        exposedHeaders="header1",allowCredentials= "false")
@RestController
public class ReservationsController {

    private ReservationDao dao;

    @Autowired
    public ReservationsController(ReservationDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @PostMapping("/reservations")
    public Map<String, String> bookReservation(@RequestBody Map<String, String> reservation) {
        System.out.println(reservation);
        return null;
    }
}
```

angular api bookReservation method:

```js
 bookReservation(data) {
    console.log(data);
    const result = this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'reservations', data).subscribe(
      (val) => {
        console.log('POST call succesful value returned in body',
          val);
      },
      response => {
        console.log('POST call in error', response);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('The POST observable is now completed');
      });
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set allowedHeaders only you will allow this params and if it receive other params it never send cross origing headers and chrome will throw error.

You should remove allowedHeaders, exposedHeaders and allowCredentials if you don't need them.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, could you explain?

Comment: if you set "allowedHeaders" in the restcontroller, it only accept these headers if it receive others, it won't working. I think this could be happening. If you remove this parameters it could work

Comment: I removed the allowedheaders and exposedheaders. This worked, please edit your answer to make it more clear and i’ll accept it as answer. Thanks my man.

Comment: I try explain better but my english is bad :'(